# Are RandomForestRegressor features handles as categories?

Tags: python, tree, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

i'm using **RandomForestRegressor** (from the great Scikt-Learn library in python) for my project,
it gives me good results, but i think i can do better.
when i'm giving features to 'fit(..)' function, 
is it better to make categorical features as binary features?

example:
instead of:

```
===========
continent |
===========
     1    |
===========
     2    |
===========
     3    |
===========
     2    |
===========
```

make something like:

```
===========================
is_europe | is_asia   | ...
===========================
    1     |     0     |
===========================
    0     |     1     |
===========================
```

because its working as a tree maybe the second option is better,
or does it will work the same for the first option?
thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binarizing categorical variables is highly recommended, and expects to outperform the model without binarizer transform. If `scikit-learn` considers `continent = [1, 2, 3, 2]` as numeric values (continuous variable [quantitative] instead of categorical [qualitative]), it imposes an artificial order constraint on that feature. For example, suppose `continent=1` means `is_europe`, `continent=2` means `is_asia`, and `continent=3` means `is_america`, then it implies that `is_asia` is always in between `is_europe` and `is_america` when examing the relation of the `continent feature` to your response variable `y`, which is not necessarily true and have a chance to reduce the model effectiveness. In contrast, making it dummy variables has no such problem and `scikit-learn` will treat each binary feature separately.

To binarize your categorical variables in `scikit-learn`, you can use `LabelBinarizer`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer


# your data
# ===========================
continent = [1, 2, 3, 2]
continent_dict = {1:'is_europe', 2:'is_asia', 3:'is_america'}
print(continent_dict)

{1: 'is_europe', 2: 'is_asia', 3: 'is_america'}

# processing
# =============================
binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
# fit on the categorical feature
continent_dummy = binarizer.fit_transform(continent)
print(continent_dummy)

[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```

If you process your data in `pandas`, then its top-level function `pandas.get_dummies` also helps.

Comment: its important to note that there is a much more natural way to do categorical features like this in decision trees/random-forests, they can't be supported in scikit-learn because the library doesn't support categorical features.